# SQLITE Update with conditions....case then?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, sql-update, case

Thanks in advance. 
I'm trying update a table with date of another table. I got this correctly, but now i want update each row only if 4 conditions are true in the original table.

```
UPDATE newtable SET Serial = CASE WHEN(
 (SELECT ETI FROM oldtable) != 0.0) 
 AND ((SELECT Serial FROM oldtable) != 0000) 
 AND ((SELECT Hardware FROM oldtable) != 0000) 
 AND ((SELECT Software FROM oldtable) != 0000)
THEN (SELECT Serial FROM oldtable  WHERE newtable.IDENT= oldtable.IDENT)END,
```

....

this update all the row, so the 4 conditions don't work.

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What is `0000` supposed to represent?  The number only needs to be `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can do this with correlated subqueries, like so:

```
update newtable
set serial = (
    select serial 
    from oldtable
    where ident = newtable.ident and serial <> 0 and hardware <> 0 and software <> 0 and eti <> 0
)
where exists (
    select serial 
    from oldtable
    where ident = newtable.ident and serial <> 0 and hardware <> 0 and software <> 0 and eti <> 0
)
```

It is quite unclear what the datatypes of columns `serial`, `hardware`, `software` and so on is. I assumed they are numbers (because the *look* like numbers). You might need to adapt this to your exact use case.